# Search: pager is shown, but results list is empty due to ignored tags

Tags: support, status-bydesign, search

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diff+tool+with+html+output&submit=search

It's shown for mee as an empty list with a pager for 100 pages:

[image]

**EDIT (1)**: I have a lot of ignored tags. So, the list is empty for this reason.

Comment: Do you have any ignored tags (e.g. [tag:html])? The list displays properly for me.

Comment: @Fabian: Yes, a lot of them. But pager should not be shown for empty list.

Comment: The ignored tags feature works client-side, so they are only filtered out on your computer, the paging is probably created server-side, I don't think this will be easily fixable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignored tags filtering is client-side, this behavior is by-design.  Supporting massive sets of ignored tags through our engine server-side just really isn't feasible, since some people have a *lot* of ignored tags.

For example, you have 67 ignored tags on Stack Overflow...that really, *really* isn't feasible to support.